# How to access custom annotation properties when using calloutAccessoryView as the sender of a segue to a new viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, segue

I have the following code to prepare for my segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    // Make sure we are acting on the correct segue
    if segue.identifier == "CreateJumpSpot", let jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC = segue.destination as? JumpSpotCreatorController {
        // Set the delegate in the JumpSpotCreatorController we're navigating to
        jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC.delegate = self
        
    } else if segue.identifier == "JumpSpotInfo", let jumpSpotInfoVC = segue.destination as? JumpSpotInfoController {
        if let senderAnnotationView = sender as? JumpSpotAnnotationView {
            jumpSpotInfoVC.titleLabel.text = senderAnnotationView.annotation?.title as? String
            jumpSpotInfoVC.imageView.image = senderAnnotationView.annotation.
        }
    }
}
```

We are focusing on the 'else if' part of the statement here.  I have a custom annotation and annotation view.  I am populating labels and imageViews in the view controller that I am segueing to, using the properties of the annotation that the user clicked on to reveal the .detailDisclosure version of the rightCalloutAccessoryView.  However that sender (.detailDisclosure of rightCalloutAccessoryView) is only allowing me to access the title and subtitle of the annotation.  As you can see when I got to the image property I stopped typing, as there was no property to access.  How can I access the properties of my custom annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Can‘t you just get the `image` by `senderAnnotationView.annotation?.image`, just like what you are doing to get the `title`?

PS: Don't depend too much on Xcode autocompletion. Sometimes it's doesn't work perfectly well.

Comment: I get the error: value of type 'MKAnnotation?' has no member 'image'. When I do that.  It seems to think that senderAnnotatoinView.annotation is an MKAnnotation, when it is actually, in fact, my custom class, JumpSpotAnnotation.  I don't know how to make it aware of that in this function.  Any annotation with the view, "JumpSpotAnnotationView" like I casted senderAnnotationView to be, is a view of a JumpSpotAnnotation, based on my mapView viewFor function etc

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.  All I had to do was adjust the code so that I had a constant of the annotation itself, and cast it as my custom class.  Here's the code:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    // Make sure we are acting on the correct segue
    if segue.identifier == "CreateJumpSpot", let jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC = segue.destination as? JumpSpotCreatorController {
        // Set the delegate in the JumpSpotCreatorController we're navigating to
        jumpSpotCreatorControllerVC.delegate = self
        
    } else if segue.identifier == "JumpSpotInfo", let jumpSpotInfoVC = segue.destination as? JumpSpotInfoController {
        if let senderAnnotationView = sender as? JumpSpotAnnotationView {
            let senderAnnotation = senderAnnotationView.annotation as? JumpSpotAnnotation
            jumpSpotInfoVC.titleLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.title
            jumpSpotInfoVC.imageView.image = senderAnnotation?.image
            jumpSpotInfoVC.descriptionLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.description
            jumpSpotInfoVC.heightLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.estimatedHeight
            jumpSpotInfoVC.warningsLabel.text = senderAnnotation?.warnings
        }
    }
}
```

The key line there is: let senderAnnotation = senderAnnotationView.annotation as? JumpSpotAnnotation